# How can a cavity with perfectly reflecting walls approximate a perfectly absorbing black body?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermal-radiation

I don't see why you can derive the black body spectrum from the mode density of the radiation inside a reflecting cavity. I do understand the mathematical side of the derivation and I know that an absorbing cavity with a small hole is the best approximation of a black body. But aren't the standing EM waves inside the cavity only there because the cavity is perfectly reflecting, determining the boundary condition of a vanishing field at the boundaries? How is this releated to a cavity with black, (perfectly) absorbing walls? Again, I do understand that the walls can't reflect all of the incoming waves, because there must be a possibility for the matter and EM waves to interact in order to establish the thermodynamic equilibrium, but then how can you look at standing waves inside the cavity, if it is not perfectly reflecting?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/170579/i-dont-understand-why-a-cavity-with-a-hole-is-a-black-body

Comment: @ArmandoEstebanQuito I already red this thread but unfortunately it didn't help much. I don't see the connection of black bodys and cavitys with perfectly reflecting waves that are not absorbing anything (because they are reflecting everything).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "*But aren't the standing EM waves inside the cavity only there because the cavity is perfectly reflecting, determining the boundary condition of a vanishing field at the boundaries?*"

Yes, only a cavity with perfectly reflecting walls can support oscillating field with fixed nodal surfaces that is known as a standing EM wave. Such EM field oscillates harmonically with single frequency.

But the EM radiation surrounding a piece of matter in thermodynamic equilibrium - blackbody radiation - is a chaotic EM field that does not oscillate harmonically or with fixed nodes; it is not a standing wave.

Neither are the standing waves necessary mathematically to resolve the EM radiation into Fourier components and proceed with the derivation of the blackbody spectrum - it is sufficient to consider imaginary cuboid of empty space where equilibrium radiation is present and apply Fourier decomposition to the EM field in this cuboid; the Fourier components considered are then not necessarily standing waves.

With this in mind, one may pose the question, why do textbooks assume the blackbody radiation is enclosed in the perfectly reflecting cavity then? Why use an assumption that is not necessary for the derivation?

The perfectly reflecting walls are considered not because the perfect reflectivity or the possibility of standing waves are somehow important for the derivation of blackbody spectrum, but because they are necessary to make the system isolated with no radiation leaks. In practice, reflective walls increase the impact of interaction of radiation with the matter inside and make equilibration easier.

Kirchhoff proposed reflective cavity as a way to construct blackbody; reflective walls allow for multiple reflections of EM waves and multiply their interactions with the piece of matter inside the cavity. With transparent or strongly absorptive walls, the radiation produced or implanted inside would not interact with the matter inside cavity enough to change its spectrum to equilibrium; it would either escape or get absorbed in the walls before it could form equilibrium with matter inside.

Theoretically, perfectly reflecting walls of cavity is the only thing that can isolate the system thermally from the outside. Such walls allow us to think of the radiation as contained in a finite volume, as having constant energy and enable us to consider thermodynamic processes that happen to such radiation. With absorptive or transparent walls, the analysis would be much more complicated, because effect of real walls on the radiation is complex and the walls would become part of the system to be described.

Experimentally, some cavity is needed to contain the radiation so the latter can interact with matter inside and evolve into equilibrium. However, the cavities that early experimenters (Pringsheim, Lummer) could use were not perfectly reflecting - even mirror surface absorbs some parts of inbound radiation. As for the piece of matter to interact with the radiation, they chose to put it on the inner side of the walls, probably to get advantage of the large surface available and so help the process of transformation of radiation into the state of thermodynamic equilibrium. They used metallic and porcelain walls covered with lamp black (soot) and metal oxides. This inner part of the wall then played the role of matter considered to be inside the cavity in order to  interact with the EM radiation and enable the process of equilibration.

> *"How is this releated to a cavity with black, (perfectly) absorbing
>   walls? Again, I do understand that the walls can't reflect all of the
>   incoming waves, because there must be a possibility for the matter and EM waves to interact in order to establish the thermodynamic equilibrium, but then how can you look at standing waves inside the cavity, if it is not perfectly reflecting? "*

The walls do not have to be perfectly absorbing; if there is matter inside the cavity, the blackbody radiation will establish itself even if the walls are perfectly reflecting. But in reality there is no such thing as perfectly reflecting wall, all walls absorb somewhat.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! So I understand that the cavity isn't the black body, but I rather look at a block body inside a cavity. The cavity is only there to 'trap' the radiation so the black body and the radiation can get into thermal equilibrium. Then am I right by saying that a cavity with absorbing walls and a smal hole (beeing a good example for a black body because of the multiple absorption of incoming waves) isn't the same concept as a reflecting cavity for trapping the radiation? I actually should have a absorbing cavity inside a reflecting cavity...

Comment: ...the first one beeing my black body, the second one beeing there to trap the radiation so the first (absorbing) cavity can get into thermal equilibrium with the radiation.

Comment: Yes, some matter with non-zero absorption coefficient is necessary for the system to behave as black body. If the only thing that is there is perfectly reflecting cavity, there is no process that would change initial EM radiation inside into equilibrium state. For example, one could have one standing wave oscillating with single frequency indefinitely.

Comment: I will repeat my query : "is this correct ? : the boundary condition on EM fields for total radiation absorbed by the surface of a black body is the same as the boundary condition of total internal reflection in an identical geometrically cavity ? and it is easier to solve the second problem?

Comment: @annav, I do not think so, there is no boundary condition known to be satisfied by EM field if the walls are made of absorptive material. This is because in such a material, the EM field does not vanish so we cannot assume that tangential component of $\mathbf E$ in the wall is zero.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand this now. Only one last question: In the german wikipedia article to cavity radiation it says that in an opaque cavity at temperature T there will be black-body radiation of temperature T inside when there is thermal equilibrium. Can you model such a cavity as perfectly reflecting cavity with an absorbing material on its walls (like in the experiments you refered to) because of its opaqueness? Or is there another reason, that you'll get the typical cavity radiation of perfectly reflecting cavitys inside this (not perfectly reflecting, but opaque) cavity?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by opaque cavity - cavity made of real material so its walls are not perfectly reflecting? In any case, if the radiation is in thermodynamic equilibrium with matter (of any sort, on the walls or not), it will be the blackbody radiation and it does not matter if the walls are perfectly reflecting or not.

Comment: I'm sorry, by opaque I meant walls that doens't transmit, but only reflect or absorb incoming radiation, so you still won't loose any radiation from inside the cavity. My question is, why do you get the same result for the inside radiation in this case and with perfeclty reflecting cavity walls with a blackbody on the inside. I mean, if the walls are also absorbing, there can be E field insinde the walls. Can you model the absorbing, but not transmitting walls as perfectly reflecting walls with an infinite thin layer of partially absorbing material on them to get the boundary conditions?

Comment: The radiation has the same spectrum in both perfectly reflective and partially absorptive cavity purely because of the assumption that radiation is in thermodynamic equilibrium with some material body and the temperature of this material body is the same in both cases. It is just because of the assumption that the temperatures are the same; it is not a result of any deep analysis.

Comment: As to the second part of your question, absorbing non-transmitting wall is a black body. I do not know what you mean by modelling such walls as perfectly reflecting walls with partially absorbing material on their inner side. If you're after spectrum of radiation in equilibrium, this will be the same as it only depends on temperature which is supposed to be the same. If you're after physical details of interaction between matter and EM field, these are different in the two cases.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I'll try to ask it differently: I understand now why you can derivate the black-body spectrum from the reflecting cavity and that the spectrum of radiation in equilibrium will be the same for every body with the same temperature. But one thing I still wonder is the following: If you have two cavitys with the exact same geometry, but one is perfectly reflecting with a black-body inside, the other one also absorbing but non-transmitting, then how can there be the same radiation inside from an electrodynamic point of view when there are different boundy conditions?

Comment: The radiation is the same only in macroscopic sense, its spectrum throughout the volume is the same. But if we focus on radiation near the walls, there is a difference; near the perfectly reflecting wall, the component of electric field parallel to the wall is near zero; near the absorbing wall, electric field does not obey such condition. So the radiation near the surfaces is not completely the same, only the radiation throughout the volume. The surface effect is usually neglected in thermodynamics, but it is there.

Comment: Thanks, I think I finally got it! I guess when you have wavelength in the size of the cavity-dimension you will note differences when you have reflecting or absorbing walls, like there is a minimum cutoff frequency for the reflecting cavity, whereas in the absorbing cavity lesser frequencies probably can exist because the boundary conditions cease to apply. Is this right? And the black-body radiation inside the cavity is then just a (really good) approximation for high frequencies, right?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.

Answer (score 2):

There is a derivation of Planck's formula from the energy given by the [Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution). This distribution has to do with the statistical

> In statistical mechanics and mathematics, a Boltzmann distribution (also called Gibbs distribution[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution)) is a probability distribution, probability measure, or frequency distribution of particles in a system over various possible states.

It describes the statistical  behavior of many particles, and the fact that the black body distribution can be derived from this ties the analogy of oscillators in a cavity, to molecules in matter.

> [Simple Derivation of Planck’s Formula](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/252/black_body_radiation.html) from the Boltzmann’s Distribution

In a sense this is logical because the individual molecules have vibrational and rotational degrees of freedom  which behave as oscillators, and define the temperature of a body. The reflection in the oven approximation does  not exist for massive bodies, and that is why power is lost according to the [various formulas](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/Planckapp.html#c1) of black body radiation .The model holds only instantaneously, because massive bodies continuously radiate to space.

Answer (score 1):

"I hope I understood the question well and it will help." Jimmy

When radiation comes to the black body, we want everything to be absorbed. So the theory must contain Maxwell equation on the surface, of course. These say that tangent magnetic field of the incident light can (but doesn't have to, it depends on few more parameters) give a rise to surface current. But tangent electric field (the current has linear dependency on the electric field most of time) must be continuous, so there must be inertial electromagnetic field inside the body all the time. The only chance to null this field is by assuming no incident light, but then we wouldn't need the black body.

Edited: The waves inside the cavity are dependent on what is scattered outside. This should be clear from the next paragraph.

This means that in resonance-regime when field is vanishing on the surface, total reflection appears, as you claimed. But when all of incident power is absorbed, you get black body. This is the same effect that could be reached by limit $\sigma_s \to \infty$ when we have ideal conductor and it can take all of energy no matter what. For real conductors we must have special setups.

**Something more**

Zel'dovich has shown that there are few regimes in rotating cylinder. When a condition $\omega < m\Omega$ is satysfied, energy can be extracted from the kinetics of the cylinder. On the other hand, when $\omega > m\Omega$ there are few frequencies when all of the incident power if absorbed by the surface. That is the "time" when we could call this behaving like the black body.

Another example is standing sphere with radius $a$. There is possibility to null the scattered power, the condition for this is
\begin{equation}
1 = \sigma_s \mu_0 c a^2 j_\ell(ka) h^{(2)}_\ell(ka),
\end{equation}
where $j_\ell$ is a spherical Bessel function and $h^{(2)}_\ell$ spherical Hankel function of the second type.

- $\omega$ is angular frequency of the incident wave, $m$ is its azimuth number and $\Omega$ is angular velocity of the cylinder (or other axially-symmetric body).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But to be honest, I didn't understand it completely. First you are talking about a black body, then you are talking of a cavity. Is the cavity your black body, or was the first part about black bodys in general? Are we talking about a black body inside a cavity or is there no cavity? I got the feeling that I haven't understood the whole idea of the relation between the radiation inside a cavity and the black body radiation.

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing structure. In the first part I wanted to say that if we have a body with cavity and we want to study absorption, we have electromagnetic waves inside the cavity too, not only outside waves that are scattering. And we must consider incident waves, because the idea is in their absorption. Then I wanted to show that there are examples in which normal bodies act like black bodies because of the currents on the surface. And the connection between inside and outside radiation is from the continuous tangent electrical field and radial magnetic field.

Comment: I think I understand. So we have a cavity and there is incoming radiation from the outside, beeing absorbed from the walls of the cavity. Because of the Maxwell equations there also must be an electromagnetic field inside the cavity (because of the interface conditions) and these waves are the standing waves. Is this correct? If yes, then do I actually need the small hole in the cavity that is often proposed to let the radiation from the inside get to the outside of the cavity? I'm sorry if I still mistunderstand the concept.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've meant. But this works for only one wavelength, so with, let us say, white light, it's not working perfectly anymore. But in real world we have velocity of light in vacuum $\sim 3 \cdot 10^8$ m/s and in the arguments is $k = \omega/c$, so it should not be measurable difference in big range of wavelengths.

Comment: is this correct ? : the boundary condition  on  EM fields for  total radiation absorbed by the surface of a black body is the same as the boundary condition of total internal reflection in an identical  geometrically cavity ? and it is easier to solve the second  problem?